# UIWebView New Url load animation effect

Tags: ios, animation, uiwebview

Can we load a new url in webview with animation when it loads effect ??
i.e. I want to give my webview an animation when it loads a new url or any link clicked on the opened website in webview.
I want to give pushviewController type animation (right to left movement of screen ) with back button on my webview to go back (left to right movement of webView view) when user taps on link / loads a new url.

Comment: while you are using html in webview you can do it by calling some animation mathod of HTML 5

Comment: Actually i am not able to get your suggestion for making my html element animated !!
I am using a third party tool , in which i m having a table view controller at left side and a webview in right hand side.
I have added one navBar in right hand side above webview containing back button.if user taps on it , webview will load previous url. I want to add here push/pop view controller type animation

Comment: if you want to show loading view , go on with @neo's answer. it seems you want to show animation while rendering between pages in webview's content. for that thing you will need to modify your webview's html content , in other words the website should apply animation using HTML5 , it can't be done from webview...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can stack a view in - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView and close it with - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView

e.g.,

WebViewController.h

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> {
 IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}
```

WebViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever a new URL is loading into UIWebView,it's

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

     //Code for animating view .
     //Code for back button.
    }
```

delegate method will be called .
    So do the stuff required for you inside this delegate method.